# Using the definition of unitary / orthogonal operators explicity for matrices:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, orthonormal

If A is unitary, then $$AA^* = A^*A = I, and\ A^* = A^{-1}$$

I want to see this explicitly for a very simple unitary matrix, say, take the column vector A = (1,0,0) and we regard this as a 3x1 orthogonal matrix.

But $AA^*$ gives a 3x3 matrix which is *not* the identity matrix but rather a matrix with a 1 in the entry $a_{11}$ and zeros everywhere else in the matrix.

So, where did things go "wrong"?

Thanks,

Comment: Only square matrices can be unitary/orthogonal.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks for the reminder, @Omnomnomnom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need that $A$ is a square matrix, not a column.

Edit: Omnomnomnom was first :)

Comment: Ok, thanks @mathematician42.